# extracting text from another file using python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a list of long text in one column in a csv file (proposal.csv) under header "proposal". This contains sentences including addresses (such as building name and postal code). I have another csv file (building.csv) with building names under the "building" column.

I'd like to extract all the building names from the sentences in the proposal column.

Is there a way to do this? I spend nearly a whole day trying to figure this out but cannot seem to get. I used the `df.isin(keywords)` method but it appears all as false.

Example of a row in the proposal column - `"i live in taj mahal and it is a very pretty place"`. I'd like to extract the term `"taj mahal"` as it is a buidling (and `taj mahal` is listed inside my building csv).

See screenshot for error:

[image: Error]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you add the code referenced in your screenshot to the post please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv

with open("proposal.csv", 'r') as file:
    sentences = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(file)]

with open("building.csv", 'r') as file:
    buildings = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(file)]

buildings_in_sentences = []
for building in buildings:
    if any(building in sentence for sentence in sentences):
            buildings_in_sentences.append(building)
```

You can also use list comprehension:

```
buildings_in_sentences = [building for building in buildings if any(
    building in sentence for sentence in sentences)]
```

To write file to csv with sentences and building keywords do:

```
import csv

with open("proposal.csv", 'r') as file:
    sentences = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(file)]

with open("building.csv", 'r') as file:
    buildings = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(file)]

output_rows = [
    [
        sentence, 
        next((b for b in buildings if b in sentence), "not_found")
    ] for sentence in sentences]

with open("proposal.out.csv", "w") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(output_rows)
```

Comment: thank you! but how to i append the fields back to the original csv (proposal.csv) and then open the file to see those that are matched and the keywords?

Comment: See my edit. Its better to create a file with a different name (for example `proposal.out.csv`). I hope that this is what your looking for.

Comment: Hi Sarartur, thank you for taking your time to reply me and help me out with this issue. i really spent more than a day trying to figure how to solve this even though there are many tutorials out there, i couldnt get a solution to my problem. thank you very much. saved me a lot of time!!!!